# How a deployed aurelia web application differs than an application that runs locally on gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia

Is there an article that describes how a deployed aurelia web application differs than an application that runs locally on gulp. This must be a general question that applies not only to aurelia. There is a js library that I'm using that hangs the browser. That never happens when I run the app locally which makes me think that there is something really different that the deployed app does not have.

Comment: If you are using SystemJS skeleton, the only difference is that the deployed version is bundled while the local version is not. Make sure that that your bundle config file is correct.

Comment: As @FabioLuz has touched on - are your bundling/exporting your App for production? Most likely you're missing some files in your deployed app - though these should cause an error in your console.

Comment: It appears either that different files are deployed than the ones I think, or that for some reason they'r functioning differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, this is not so much Aurelia specific, but build-tool specific. When you run your app locally, you will be using npm dependencies that are installed in `/node_modules` directory and resources from local file system (like CSS, images etc). When you bundle your application for deployment you need to bundle everything needed to run the app (including dependencies and resources).

For every bundler you can configure what to bundle and create different bundles. There are good explanations on how to bundle for both [Aurelia CLI project](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/9) (bundle configuration is in `aurelia_project/aurelia.json`) and [JSPM project](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/bundling-jspm/1) (bundle configuration is in `bundle.js`).

Just make sure that all necessary files and modules are bundled. Often the problem is not with bundling itself, but stuff that cannot be bundled. There are some very stubborn libraries (eg some assets of Bootstrap or some jQuery-based plugins) that will not work when bundled. Then you need to include them in deployment separately. In JSPM configuration it means you will have to export them together with bundles. Export basicly means "select all files that will be used to run the app in production" and those files are going to be copied to `/export` directory in case of JSPM. In CLI installation you will need to add `copyFiles` section to aurelia.json to export extra files.

Check [this article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/the-definitive-guide-to-bundling-exporting-in-aurelia/) on how bundling exactly works and [this one](http://blog.aurelia.io/2015/09/11/bundling-aurelia-apps/) to understand what is the role of aurelia-bundler in the process (hint: aurelia-bundler is a part of framework that creates ready-to-use Gulp tasks for you).